# Wrap a single oversize column with awk / bash (pretty print)

Tags: bash, awk, pretty-print

Im having this table structure (assume that the delimiters are tabs):

```
AAA  BBBB  CCC
 01  Item  Description here
 02  Meti  A very very veeeery long description which will easily extend the recommended output width of 80 characters.
 03  Etim  Last description
```

What i want is this:

```
AAA  BBBB  CCC
 01  Item  Description here
 02  Meti  A very very veeeery
           long description which
           will easily extend the
           recommended output width
           of 80 characters.
 03  Etim  Last description
```

That means I want to split `$3` into an array of strings with predefined `WIDTH`, where the first element is appended "normally" to the current line and all subsequent elements get a new line width identation according to the padding of the first two columns (padding could also be fixed if thats easier).

Alternatively, the text in `$0` could be split by a `GLOBAL_WIDTH` (e.g. 80 chars) into first string and "rest" -> first string gets printed "normally" with printf, the rest is split by `GLOBAL_WIDTH - (COLPAD1 + COLPAD2)` and appended width new lines as above.

I tried to work with `fmt` and `fold` after my awk formatting (which is basically just putting headings to the table) but they do not reflect awk's field perceptance of course.

How can I achieve this using bash tools and / or awk?

Comment: Please do mention the logic of dividing them into new lines along with your efforts in your post.

Comment: I don't have any logic available because I simply don't know how to do it. The example above is just created by hand in an editor. Can you point me to a reference where I can find some first answers?

Comment: I got it that you have written it by hand but there will be some condition by  which your expected output will come(dividing lines into different new lines), I was referring to that logic here.

Comment: Ah I see, I hope it's clearer now.

Comment: Ok but what should be length of 3rd field which we are dividing into new lines, from your sample it is not clear kindly do mention that too.

Comment: There's no specific size, I wanted the user of my script to configure this by themselves, this is why I used WIDTH and GLOBAL_WIDTH instead of constant ints (e.g. via the -v switch). But for this example let's say $3 should contain 50 chars at most, everything above should be split.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First build a test file (called `file.txt`):

```
echo "AA  BBBB  CCC
01  Item  Description here
02  Meti  A very very veeeery long description which will easily extend the recommended output width of 80 characters.
03  Etim  Last description" > file.txt
```

Now the script (called `./split-columns.sh`):

```
#!/bin/bash
FILE=$1

#find position of 3rd column (starting with 'CCC')
padding=`cat $FILE | head -n1 |  grep -aob 'CCC' | grep -oE '[0-9]+'`
paddingstr=`printf "%-${padding}s" ' '`

#set max length
maxcolsize=50
maxlen=$(($padding + $maxcolsize))

cat $FILE | while read line; do 
  #split the line only if it exceeds the desired length
  if [[ ${#line} -gt $maxlen ]] ; then 
    echo "$line" | fmt -s -w$maxcolsize - | head -n1
    echo "$line" | fmt -s -w$maxcolsize - | tail -n+2 | sed "s/^/$paddingstr/"
  else
    echo "$line";
  fi; 
done;
```

Finally run it with the file as a single argument

```
./split-columns.sh file.txt > fixed-width-file.txt
```

Output will be:

```
AA  BBBB  CCC
01  Item  Description here
02  Meti  A very very veeeery long description
          which will easily extend the recommended output
          width of 80 characters.
03  Etim  Last description
```

Comment: Thanks, that seems like a nice bash only solution!

Comment: In all fairness I should point out, this solution does NOT wrap a single column, it wraps the final part of the line. It works fine in this case because you only want to wrap the final column.

Answer (score 3):

You can try Perl one-liner

```
perl -lpe ' s/(.{20,}?)\s/$1\n\t   /g ' file
```

with the given inputs

```
$ cat thurse.txt
AAA  BBBB  CCC
 01  Item  Description here
 02  Meti  A very very veeeery long description which will easily extend the recommended output width of 80 characters.
 03  Etim  Last description

$ perl -lpe ' s/(.{20,}?)\s/$1\n\t   /g ' thurse.txt
AAA  BBBB  CCC
 01  Item  Description
           here
 02  Meti  A very very
           veeeery long description
           which will easily extend
           the recommended output
           width of 80 characters.
 03  Etim  Last description

$
```

If you want to try with length window of 30/40/50

```
$ perl -lpe ' s/(.{30,}?)\s/$1\n\t   /g ' thurse.txt
AAA  BBBB  CCC
 01  Item  Description here
 02  Meti  A very very veeeery
           long description which will easily
           extend the recommended output width
           of 80 characters.
 03  Etim  Last description

$ perl -lpe ' s/(.{40,}?)\s/$1\n\t   /g ' thurse.txt
AAA  BBBB  CCC
 01  Item  Description here
 02  Meti  A very very veeeery long description
           which will easily extend the recommended
           output width of 80 characters.
 03  Etim  Last description

$ perl -lpe ' s/(.{50,}?)\s/$1\n\t   /g ' thurse.txt
AAA  BBBB  CCC
 01  Item  Description here
 02  Meti  A very very veeeery long description which
           will easily extend the recommended output width of
           80 characters.
 03  Etim  Last description

$
```

Comment: That's very elegant, unfortunately I dont have perl available in my case :/.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
# Read standard input, which should be a file of lines each line
#  containing tab-separated strings.  The string values may be very long.
# Columnate the output by
# wrapping long strings onto multiple lines within each field's
#  specified length.
# Arguments are numeric field lengths.  If an input line contains more
# values than the # of field lengths supplied, the last field length will 
# be re-used.
#
# arguments are the field lengths
# invoke like this: wrapcolumns 30 40 40

BEGIN {
FS="    ";
for (i = 1; i < ARGC; i++) {
    fieldlengths[i-1] = ARGV[i];
    ARGV[i]="";
    }
if (ARGC < 2) {
    print "usage: wrapcolumns length1 ... lengthn";
    exit;
}
}


function blanks(n) {
    result = "                                  ";
    while (length(result) < n) {
        result = result result;
    }
    return substr(result, 1, n);
}

{

# ARGC - 1 is the length of the fieldlengths array
# So ARGC - 2 is the index of its last element because its zero-origin.
# if the input line has more fields than the fieldlengths array,
# use the last element.

# any nonempty fields left?
gotanyleft = 1;

while (gotanyleft == 1) {
    gotanyleft = 0;
    for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) {
        # length of the current field
        len = (ARGC - 2 < i) ? (fieldlengths[ARGC - 2]) : fieldlengths[i - 1];
        # print that much of the current field and remove that much from the front
        printf "%s", substr($(i) blanks(len), 1, len) ":::"
    $(i) = substr($(i), len + 1);
    if ($(i) != "") {
        gotanyleft = 1;
    }
    }
    print ""
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

loop-free `awk`-solution :

```
{m,g}awk -v ______="${WIDTH}" 'BEGIN {
 1      OFS = ""
 1       FS = "\t"
 1      ___ = "\32\23"
 1       __ = sprintf("\n%*s", 
                     (_+=_^=_<_)+_^!_+(_+=_____=_+=_+_)+_____,__)
 1     ____ = sprintf("%*s",______-length(__),"")
 1                                   gsub(".",".",____)
       sub("[.].......$","..?.?.?.?.?.?.?.[ ]",____)
 1   ______ = _

 } $!NF = sprintf("%.*s %*s %-*s %-s", _<_,_= $NF,_____,
                  $2,______, $--NF, substr("",gsub(____,
                 ("&")___,_) * gsub("("(___)")+$","",_),
                          __ * gsub( (___), (__),_) )_)'
```

|

```
AAA BBBB         CCC
 01 Item         Description here
 02 Meti         A very very veeeery long description which 
                 will easily extend the recommended output 
                 width of 80 characters.
 03 Etim         Last description
```